# Batch String manipulation get first 3 Blocks

Tags: string, batch-file, assembly

I have an AssemblyInfo with the version number in the following format :

> 1.1.0.0

But now I want only the first 3 numbers so

> 1.1.0

and not the 4 block. But only the first 3 blocks.

My script looks like this.

```
@echo off
REM extract version from assembly ignoring commented out version
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=1^,2^* %%A IN ('findstr /L /B /C:"[assembly: AssemblyVersion" "AssemblyInfo.cs"') DO (

   set "version=%%B"
)
echo %version%
```

How can I get a variable where only the first 3 blocks are in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the information from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), your version number can be in the form:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")]
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")]
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
```

And assuming that comments begin a line with `//`

I would offer the following example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For %%G In (Build, Major, Minor, Revision, Version) Do Set "%%G="
For /F EOL^=/^ Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"\<\[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"" "AssemblyInfo.cs"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=." %%H In ("%%G"
) Do Set /A Major=%%H, Minor=%%I, Build=%%J, Revision=%%K 2> NUL
If Defined Build (Set "Version=%Major%.%Minor%.%Build%"
) Else If Defined Minor Set "Version=%Major%.%Minor%.*"
Set Version 2> NUL
Pause
```

The last line is optional, and was included only in the case that you run this directly from the GUI. In those cases, it allows you to view any output before the window closes. The line above it just provides you with the variable name and value, if one has been defined, you could also replace that with `If Defined Version Echo %Version%`, if you prefer.